# detect notifications if app is launched directly

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

using PhoneGap and the pushPlugin for notifications, is there a way to detect the notification when app is launched directly?

i.e, if someone clicks on the notification, the app launches and i can detect the notification info with the onNotificationAPN() function, but if the user ignores the notification and then open the app directly, even though it has the little red notification number the onNotificationAPN() isn't fired.

Comment: You want to detect if your app was launched via the notification, right? And you're also saying that if someone clicks on the notification, the onNotificationAPN callback is fired. So  where's the problem? As soon as the user launches your app directly via the notification, onNotificationAPN will be fired and then you now. But I guess I didn't understanding you correctly. Some clarification would be desireable.

Comment: I have the same problem: I can know when someone started the app from the notification but when he starts the app directly, there is no way to know that is has not been started from notification since the call is asynchronous

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Have a look a this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507469/change-state-when-user-selects-notification-from-ios-notification-center-in-cord/29505929#29505929)