# Change State when User Selects Notification from iOS Notification Center in Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm attempting to open an iOS/Ionic/Cordova app at a specific message/state (given an ID), when a user clicks on a message push notification in the notification center.  Is there a way to tell, using Cordova, if the app has been opened through the notification center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#ecb-amazon-fire-os-android-and-ios), the callback is the point of entry for your notification. Any calls you make (or variables you set) inside the callback will only be possible if the app has been opened through the notification center