# Cordova - How can I tell what triggered the app open?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

How can I tell, in cordova, if the app was started because of a regular click on the icon, or a click on the push notification, *before* the 'onNotification' is called?

I'm using the push-plugin, but until the 'notification' event is called, I'm already within the app itself, and the view "jumps" to the new notification event, which doesn't look good.

Comment: Wha's about to send some data with the notification?

Answer (score 0):

Any code you put in the `onNotification` callbacks will only be triggered if the application was launched by clicking on the notification.

*UPDATE*

- To prevent your view from jumping to new notification event, add conditionals to check state and prevent or pause view 'jumps'.

*See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29505929/1761793) I wrote for iOS.*

Comment: I want to know that before I'm inside the onNotification :)

Comment: The `onNotification` is the callback for your use case. If you need to override that, theoretically, you will have to modify the plugin; add another callback that triggers before `onNotification`. But that doesn't make sense! Perhaps you could elaborate why exactly you need that.